# Help finding IC with marking on device '14260P TI 28A P034G4'. Package of device is SOIC-8

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, identification, markings

IC identification

- package: SOIC-8
- top marking: 14260P TI 28A P034G4

[image]

Comment: If https://www.ti.com/packaging/docs/partlookup.tsp does not find it, then it's likely to be a discontinued or customer-specific device.

Comment: it appears to be LV14260P, but I only found a [packaging document](https://www.ti.com/packaging/docs/carriermaterial/downloadCarrierReport?OPN=LV14260PDDAR).  There is an LV14*3*60 in a similar package, it's possible it's related.  [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lv14360.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

It's a Texas Instruments LV14260PDDAR. According to [this thread](https://e2echina.ti.com/support/power-management/f/power-management-forum/163305/lv14260/476934) on the official Chinese TI forum, it's a special variant of the [LMR16020](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr16020.pdf) and has the same specifications.

[image]

(Source: [e2echina.ti.com](https://e2echina-ti-com.translate.goog/support/power-management/f/power-management-forum/163305/lv14260/476934?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp) [google translated])

Comment: That's great sleuthing!  After a quick comparison, the LMR16020 and [LV14360](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lv14360.pdf) appear very related, with the latter having a higher current rating.  Both parts appear to be current with thousands in stock at large distributors.